# Как вызвать класс зная его имя?

Tags: python, классы

У меня есть класс с заданными элементами.
Я знаю имя элемента (.name характеристика) в виде строчки. Как мне получить имея эту строчку (допустим 'apple', имя объекта .name тоже 'apple') другие заданные характеристики объекта apple - массу, размеры геометрические?

Comment: создать массив со всеми объектами класса/-ов, потом пробежаться по нему, и для каждого из элементов проверять, равно ли name - "apple"?

Comment: К сожалению, все объекты класса заданы "вручную" внутри кода в виде списка в  20000 объектов свернутых в спойлер. Нет более быстрого способа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Класс у вас уже есть, привёл его просто для примера
class products(object):

    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.weight = weight
        self.name = name


# Ваши 20000 объектов, которые уже есть в коде:
o1 = products('banana', 1)
o2 = products('apple', 2)
# ....
o20000 = products('cherry', 3)

# А вам нужно дописать что-то подобное
# Перебираем все объекты в области видимости
for obj in locals().values():
    # Если объект является экземпляром класса products
    # и его свойство name равно 'apple'
    if isinstance(obj, products) and obj.name == 'apple':
        # Напечатаем значение его свойства weight
        print(obj.weight)

# Напечатает только число 2, т.к. именно такой weight у объекта с name == 'apple'
```

Comment: Продублировал ваш код для своего класса - получил ошибку:
dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Я немного правил ответ, возможно, вы запускали более раннюю версию. Проверьте, что у вас эта строка выглядит именно так, как сейчас у меня: for obj in locals().values():

Comment: for obj in locals().values():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
Ругается именно на эту строку.

Comment: Странно, вроде не должно... Попробуйте так: for obj in locals().copy().values():

Comment: `import copy; copy.deepcopy(locals().values())` ?

Comment: Спасибо большое всем, заработало! Я правда не совсем понял как это сработало, но ошибка исчезла.

Answer (score 0):

```
class le_class():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.weight = a
        self.sort = b

test = le_class(3,'red')
print(test.weight)
print(test.__dict__) # вернет словарь атрибутов экземпляра класса
print(test.__class__.__name__) # вернет имя класса-родителя
```

на выходе:

```
3
{'weight': 3, 'sort': 'red'}
le_class
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял как использовать класс, который Вы указали. Прошу прощения, если ответ очевиден, осваиваю python 5 день и могу делать глупые ошибки.

Comment: Проблема в том, что данные уже исходные заданы в коде в виде:
apple = products('apple', weight=20, linear=3). Я получаю строчку 'apple' и хочу используя ее узнать weight элемента apple.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу **Александр**а, можете создавать переменные, генерируя их название динамически.

```
# ...
for i in [("Apple", 2), ("Banana", 10), ("Pineapple", 4)]:
    globals()["fruit%s" % i[0] = Fruit("%s" % i[0], i[1])
```

Создастся **N** объектов класса `Fruit`, доступ к которым можно будет получить, зная только их название.

```
o = globals()["fruitApple"].weight # 2
```

Благодаря такому подходу можно будет не перебирать абсолютно все объекты, что сократит время исполнения.

Comment: Спасибо большое , буду знать, к сожалению базу данных для класса вбивал не я, а вбивать столько данных заново желания нет.

Comment: у вас и правда 20.000 строк занято одними только объектами классов?

Comment: Да, я получил его как дефолтный код, который нужно доработать и исправить в качестве задания в рамках обучения в универе. 1200 - 1500 строк самого кода, написанного мной и 20000 на этот класс.